# Retonar todos os valores em Array stdClass Object

Tags: php

Gostaria de ajuda.
Tenho um Array que retorna os seguintes valores:

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
      (
         [seccionalid] => 1
         [seccionaldescricao] => DELSECPOL DE SJRIO PRETO
      )

   [1] => stdClass Object
      (
         [seccionalid] => 2
         [seccionaldescricao] => DELSECPOL DE JALES
      )

   [2] => stdClass Object
      (
         [seccionalid] => 3
         [seccionaldescricao] => DELSECPOL DE ARAÇATUBA
      )
```

Estou tentando com `echo` ou `print_r`, retornar para uma função, todos os valores de `[seccionaldescricao]` do `Array`, da seguinte forma:

```
$dados = $seccionais->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$dados2 = $dados[0]->seccionaldescricao;

print_r($dados2);
```

No entanto, é retornada apenas uma linha:

`DELSECPOL DE SJRIOPRETO`

Como faço para retornar todos os registros?

Answer (score 2):

Parece que você precisa criar uma nova array só com esses dados. Pode ser manualmente, usando um loop, como na resposta do André Baill, ou usando a função [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), assim:

```
function descricoes($item) {
    return $item->seccionaldescricao;
}
$dados2 = array_map(descricoes, $dados);
print_r($dados2);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda bfavaretto;

Comment: A rotina deu quase certo. Apenas retornou desta forma:

2<br,>
<b>Notice<,b>; Use of undefined constant descricoes -  assumed 'descricoes' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ContagemDeTempo\classes\....."

Array
(
  [0] => DELSECPOL DE SJRIO PRETO
  [1] => DELSECPOL DE Jales
  [2] => DELSECPOL DE Araçatuba

Somente para esclarecer: Estou tentando jogar estes valores dentro de um combobox. Este combobox chega até a ser carregado, mas com toda a mensagem do erro e com todos os ítens do Array em uma linha só (não insere linha-a-linha);

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode elaborar da seguinte forma:

```
$dados = $seccionais->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
foreach($dados as $valor){
    echo $valor->seccionaldescricao;
    echo "<br>";    
}
```

Desta forma ele buscará os arrays() que você destinou e fará a impressão de acordo com o campo que você quiser.

Comment: Consegui fazer através da sugestão do André Baill. O único ponto ficou com relação ao ítem 0 do Array que concatenou o nr. 2 (dois). Ficou assim no combobox: 2DELSECPOL DE SJRIO PRETO
DELSECPOL DE Jales
DELSECPOL DE Araçatuba Poderia me dizer de onde veio este nr. 2, já que não está na base de dados? Mais uma vez, obrigado.

Comment: Obs.: Somente para esclarecer. O três itens foram carregados em linhas separadas (quebradas). O único problema é com relação ao nr. 2 concatenado.

Comment: Cole seu SQL aqui... Mas não era pra vir o numero 2 junto. Consegue colar um print do resultado?

Comment: Coloque `echo "<br><br><br>";` antes do `foreach` e veja se o `2` está concatenado @Vanderci

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um array de objetos, como exemplo eu fiz a seguinte entrada da sua coleção:

```
<?php
$myCollection = [
    new stdClass(),
    new stdClass(),
    new stdClass(),
    ];

 //como no seu exemplo, você tem 3 posições do array que cada uma representa 2 atributos de um objeto stdClass 
    $myCollection[0]->seccionalid = 1;
    $myCollection[0]->seccionaldescricao = 'DELSECPOL DE SJRIO PRETO';

    $myCollection[1]->seccionalid = 2;
    $myCollection[1]->seccionaldescricao = 'DELSECPOL DE JALES';

    $myCollection[2]->seccionalid = 3;
    $myCollection[2]->seccionaldescricao = 'DELSECPOL DE ARAÇATUBA';

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myCollection);

class PHPIterator implements Iterator
    {
        private $collection = [];
        private $key        = 0;

        public function __construct(array $collection = [])
        {
            $this->collection = $collection;
        }

        public function rewind()
        {
            $this->key = 0;
        }

        public function current()
        {
            return $this->collection[$this->key];
        }

        public function key()
        {
            return $this->key;
        }

        public function next()
        {
            ++$this->key;
        }

        public function valid()
        {
            return isset($this->collection[$this->key]);
        }
    }

    //aqui você faz a interação:
    $phpIterator = new PHPIterator($myCollection);

    //abaixo eu faço com três casos de interação
    echo "-----------------while--------------------\n";

     $phpIterator->rewind();

    while ($phpIterator->valid()) {

        echo $phpIterator->current()->seccionalid."\n";
        echo $phpIterator->current()->seccionaldescricao."\n";
        $phpIterator->next();
    }

    echo "-------------------for--------------------\n";


    for ($phpIterator->rewind(); $phpIterator->valid(); $phpIterator->next()) {
        echo $phpIterator->current()->seccionalid."\n";
        echo $phpIterator->current()->seccionaldescricao."\n";
    }


    echo "------------------foreach-----------------\n";

    foreach ($phpIterator as $key => $object) {
       echo $object->seccionalid."\n";
       echo $object->seccionaldescricao."\n";
    }
```

A documentação do PHP tem mais informações sobre este design pattern:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.iterator.php

Agora usando uma forma mais básica, sem design pattern, você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
    //Suponha que sua coleção seja essa:
            $myCollection = [
            new stdClass(),
            new stdClass(),
            new stdClass(),
            ];

         //como no seu exemplo, você tem 3 posições do array que cada uma representa 2 atributos de um objeto stdClass 
            $myCollection[0]->seccionalid = 1;
            $myCollection[0]->seccionaldescricao = 'DELSECPOL DE SJRIO PRETO';

            $myCollection[1]->seccionalid = 2;
            $myCollection[1]->seccionaldescricao = 'DELSECPOL DE JALES';

            $myCollection[2]->seccionalid = 3;
            $myCollection[2]->seccionaldescricao = 'DELSECPOL DE ARAÇATUBA';
//lembrando que a variável $myCollection é uma simples representação do retorno de: $dados = $seccionais->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if (count($myCollection)) {
    foreach($myCollection as $data) {
       echo $data->seccionalid.'<br>';
       echo $data->seccionaldescricao.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Aqui o exemplo funcionando:
http://viper-7.com/IXwoVj

Comment: Uma das coisas que muita gente confunde é que quando o array não tem índices ou chaves definido(a)s, estes índices passam a ser 0, 1, 2, 3... e cada índice representa um elemento do array. Arrays podem ser definidos por `[]` ou por `array()`, e estas chaves podem receber valores que são atribuídos por `=>`

Answer (score 1):

Quando você acessa `->` está se referenciando a um atributo com `1` item, para acessar todos, você precisará criar um loop:

```
foreach($seccionais as $result){
    echo($result->seccionaldescricao);
}
```

> ou

```
while ($row = $seccionais->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$seccionaldescricao= $row['seccionaldescricao'];
}
```